# Is it possible to run sqlite queries conditionally in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm using node v14.2 and sqlite3: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3

I'm trying to determine if a table exists, and if it does, make a query against it. I've tried:

```js
data = []
db.run("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable';", result => {
    console.log(result)
    if (result) {
        db.each("SELECT * FROM mytable;", (err, row) => {
            data.push(row)
        })
    }
})
console.log(data)
```

However, my array `data` never gets pushed to, even when the table `mytable` exists. I've also tried testing for table existence with `PRAGMA table_info('mytable');`. How could I add to `data` once I confirm that `mytable` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. `db.run()`'s second argument, `result`, is null if the query was successful and error if it was not. Thus, I should error if `result`, rather than the opposite. Here's the working code:

```js
data = []
db.run("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable';", result => {
    if (result) {
        console.error(result)
    } else {
        db.each("SELECT * FROM mytable;", (err, row) => {
            data.push(row)
        })
    }
    console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see in your code is, the console.log is outside of the callback function.

```
data = []
db.all("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable';", function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
        data.push(row)
    });
    console.log(data)
});
```

What you need to understand in JS is, the callbacks are async and might get called after the next line gets executed. In your case, most likely the console.log got executed before the call back finished.

Update: Just realised the run function does not return anything.

Comment: That's a good note, but the same issue still occurs when I move `console.log()` into the callback. The inner `db.each()` does not run because `result` is null.

Comment: @wcarhart Just realised that, the run function does not return anything

Comment: Figured out the problem, in case you were wondering, see my answer